# Using WebAuthn with Windows Hello (PIN) through rdp doesn't work

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-hello

I have set up Windows Hello on my laptop (W10 N 1903), and can use the demo at https://webauthn.io/ just fine if I am using the laptop directly.

However when I rdp from my desktop into the laptop (using my windows user's password) and then try to use the demo, [it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJaK4.png).

Is this a bug or intentional? Does windows hide the hello authenticator from remote sessions for some reason? In case of the former, where should I raise it? In case of the latter, can I turn that off?

Both machines are not part of a domain.

Comment: Would that require a dedicated implementation?

Comment: I assume my browser talks to windows hello through some specified channel - why would that channel require a different implementation just because the browser was spawned in an rdp session and not a mundane local one? I don't want to log into rdp with hello, I want to use it on the client I successfully rdp-ed to.

Comment: Again: My firefox on my laptop cannot talk to the hello *on the very same laptop*. There doesn't have to be "magic over rdp" involved, since both the browser and hello service are on the same machine!

Comment: Sorry, got the direction wrong. Still, it’s not entirely surprising Windows Hello is disabled when it cannot verify your identity locally.